# open image link overlay (lightbox effect)

Tags: jquery, html, image, href, lightbox

I'm using an diy slideshow on my website.
I'm trying to open the full size photo of the thumbnail photo in an overlay, like a lightbox, with using a link, like in my code below, I need to use href because I'm using custom fields on the website.

here is my html :

```
<div class="slide">

<a href="http://collapsingmarket.com/wp-content/uploads/fly_1-400x566.jpg" class="full"/>
    <img src="http://collapsingmarket.com/wp-content/uploads/fly_1-211x300.jpg" class="thumbnail"/>
</a>

</div>
```

I don't know where to start to achieve this... using jquery I guess

can anyone help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you share with us what you have tried? If not, there are hundreds of lightbox tutorials available online.

Comment: Why not just use a lightbox? Most lightboxes use `a` tags.

Answer (score 3):

First make a div

```
<div style="display:none;z-index:999;position:absolute">
    <img/>
</div>
```

On click a tag first put

```
e.preventdefault()
```

Then show div with

```
$('div img').attr('src',$(this).attr('href')).show()
```

you can give top and left etc of image as per requirments
if needed you can put a mask